# How to pass the current/main model data to the eagerloading constraint for use as a variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

```
$studentIds = ExamRoutineDetail::where('routine_id', $routineId)
        ->distinct()
        ->pluck('student_id')
        ->all();

    $data = Student::whereIn('id', $studentIds)
        ->where('school_id', $schoolId)
        ->where('grade_id', $gradeId)
        ->with([
            'routine_detail'                                    => function ($query) use ($routineId) {
                $query->where('routine_id', $routineId);
            },
            'routine_detail.routine',
            'routine_detail.routine.routine_info'               => function ($query) use ($routineId) {
                $query->where('routine_id', $routineId);
            },
            'routine_detail.routine.routine_info.student_marks' => function ($query) use ($studentIds) {
                $query->where('student_id', $studentIds);
            },
        ])
        ->get();
```

I want to use the student's id in the final where condition in the last layer of the nested eagerloading i.e. routine_detail.routine.routine_info.student_marks.

so something like this

```
'routine_detail.routine.routine_info.student_marks' => function ($query) use ($studentIds) {
                $query->where('student_id', $id);
            },
```

where id would be equal to the id of the student in context, from the main Student:: ....   model.

Comment: Why don't you use whereIn, like. `'routine_detail.routine.routine_info.student_marks' => function ($query) use ($studentIds) {
                $query->whereIn('student_id', $studentIds);
            },`

Comment: @NazemMahmud is correct, you're mixing `where` and `whereIn` clauses with the same data.